# mpi cant detect my cpu's cores intel i3 m350

Tags: c, mpi

my cpu is intel i3 m350 when i compile and run this example:

```
#include < mpi.h>   /* PROVIDES THE BASIC MPI DEFINITION AND TYPES */
#include  < stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int my_rank; 
    int size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); /*START MPI */

    /*DETERMINE RANK OF THIS PROCESSOR*/
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank); 

    /*DETERMINE TOTAL NUMBER OF PROCESSORS*/
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPICH_NAME;

    printf("Hello world! I'm rank %d of size %d\n", my_rank, size);

    MPI_Finalize();  /* EXIT MPI */
    getchar();

}
```

outputs is:

```
             Hello world! I'm rank0  of size 1
```

that means its not detect my 4 cores.what is problem?

Answer (score 4):

You need to start your program with [`mpirun`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpirun). With `mpirun` you can specify how many processes MPI should use. In your case this would look like

```
~# mpirun -n 4 ./your-program
```

Also, you might want to look at [the Open MPI FAQ](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#simple-spmd-run) (assuming, that you're using Open MPI).